# I am trying to visualize the NHANES dataset using the PAXINTEN of the individual which is intensity recorded by accelerometer

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics

I am running the following code:

```
Patient1 <- Patient1 %>%
  group_by(PAXDAY, cumsum(PAXINTEN != 0)) %>%
  mutate(Group_Label = "Active") %>%
  mutate(Group_Label = replace(Group_Label, cumsum(PAXINTEN == 0) >= 20 & cumsum(PAXINTEN == 0) <= 180, "Inactive")) %>%
  mutate(Group_Label = replace(Group_Label, cumsum(PAXINTEN == 0) > 20 & cumsum(PAXINTEN == 0) <= 300, "Non-wear")) %>%
  mutate(Group_Label = replace(Group_Label, cumsum(PAXINTEN == 0) > 20 & cumsum(PAXINTEN == 0) <= 9000, "Sleep")) %>%
  ungroup()


plots <- lapply(groups, function(group) {
  data <- filter(Patient1, PAXDAY == group)  # Filter data for each group
  ggplot(data = data) +
    aes(x = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H:%M"), y = PAXINTEN, color = Group_Label) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = paste("Missing Data Chunks for Patient 1 -", group),
         x = "Time of Day",
         y = "Intensity of activity") +
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M", date_breaks = "4 hours") +
    theme_minimal()
})

# Print the plots
for (i in seq_along(plots)) {
  print(plots[[i]])
}
```

which gives me the following image:

[image]

But What I want to see is if it has zeros more than 300, It should automatically label the whole period as sleep, which is not happening below in image and it is giving me all the different labels I have and then finally the sleep. How can I modify my code?